# identifying id of listitem for contextmenu

Tags: android, contextmenu, listitem

I have a View that extends Activity. A ListView will display a number of listitems. When the user long clicks I would like to present them with a contextmenu allowing them to select edit, delete etc... and then identify the listitem that was selected as the item to perform the action on.

In onCreate I have:

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(onListClick);
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(onListLongClick);
registerForContextMenu(listView);
```

I have a method onCreateContextMenu

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Context Menu");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Edit");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Delete");

}
```

and also onContextItemSelected

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getTitle() == "Edit") {
        // edit action
    } else if (item.getTitle() == "Delete") {
        // delete action
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I am not sure where to go from here to get the correct row/listitem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `AdapterContextMenuInfo` please refer [Link-1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo.html) from the code you provided,

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getTitle() == "Edit") {
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        editInfo(info.position);
    } else if (item.getTitle() == "Delete") {
        // TODO Delete action
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Great that works but it appears to be offset by one so instead of info.position I am having to pass in (info.position + 1). Is that expected behaviour?